# How to make all the four quadrants visible in a graph with the x axis and y axis in the center

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I need both the axes to be shown in the graph in the middle so that it makes a cross-like a shape at the middle when they intersect(so that I can represent the zero of graph of a quadratic geometrically)This is the code I used, how can i edit it so that the result of the graph is like my expected outcome

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = float(input("Enter the value of x    "))
a = float(input("Enter the value of a    "))
b = float(input("Enter the value of b    "))
c = float(input("Enter the value of c    "))
x = []
y = []
for i in range(-1000, 1000, 1):
    x.append(i)
    t = (a * (i ** 2)) + (b * i) + c
    y.append(t)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')

ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I expect the graph to be like this

[image: Graph of a quadratic function with two real roots]

But instead, this is the sort of output

[image: Graph with no lower two quadrants]

Comment: Set your [xlimits](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html) and [ylimits](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html)

Comment: How do i do this???

Comment: By looking at the links I posted, and using those commands exactly the way your code uses the other `ax.` commands, in accordance with the examples on the linked documentation pages. Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, and we ask that you at least try to implement something, then ask specific questions about what went wrong with your attempt

Comment: I'm not sure why you `import math` and then don't use it...And also your for loop is not indented and a copy/paste of your code will result in a syntax error

Comment: I think your code already does what you want. If you set values like this, it looks about right to me: `a = 2; b = 3; c = -40`. Use `ax.set_ylim(-200, 50)` (for example) to change the axis limits. You can also do your range over way fewer points, like `range(-10, 10)`, and it'll be much faster for this example. You can also delete the `set_ticks_position` as those are the defaults.

Comment: did you get any answer for this question? @IsaamThalhath